# Al Actualizar un Div con jQuery o Ajax dejan de funcionar los componentes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Estoy utilizando un template que encontré en internet, cuando hago clic en una opción del menú actualizo el contenido principal por medio de `Ajax` pero cuando quiero contraer un `div` o abrir un `datepicker`, o cualquier otra funcionalidad de `jquery`, ya no es posible hacer nada de esto en todo el `html` que cargue por `Ajax`.

[image: Componentes funcionando]

Esta es la pagina que se carga por defecto, aquí pueden ver que funciona el `datepicker` y el `collapse` de los `divs` de abajo, pero cuando cargo otro `HTML` por `Ajax` y lo muestro ya no puedo usar ninguna de esas opciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice para solucionar el `collapse` de los `divs`, fue buscar el código de `javascript` que activa eso y copiarlo en un nuevo archivo de esta manera:

```
$(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse-link').on('click', function() {
        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel'),
            $ICON = $(this).find('i'),
            $BOX_CONTENT = $BOX_PANEL.find('.x_content');

        // fix for some div with hardcoded fix class
        if ($BOX_PANEL.attr('style')) {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200, function(){
                $BOX_PANEL.removeAttr('style');
            });
        } else {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200); 
            $BOX_PANEL.css('height', 'auto');  
        }

        $ICON.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });

    $('.close-link').click(function () {
        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel');

        $BOX_PANEL.remove();
    });
});

});
```

Eso soluciono ese problema, pero para poder hacer que todas las funcionalidades de la plantilla estén operativas tendré que buscar por toda la plantilla las partes de código de cada funcionalidad y agregarla a mi archivo `javascript` que cargo con cada página nueva que abro por medio de `Ajax`.

Saben alguna manera de poder solucionar esto sin tener que cargar todos los `javascript` cada vez que cargo una nueva pagina por `Ajax`.

Comment: Hola Andres, una de las cosas que yo particular mente hago cuando trabajo con formularios dinámicos(con ajax) es poner las funcionalidades agregadas en una función. Así, Cuando inicio con document.ready por ejemplo, solo tengo que llamar a esa función una sola vez. O puedo usarlo luego de una llamada ajax. Al terminar de "construir" algo dinámicamente. Solo tienes que llamas a esa funcion. Otra recomendación es que pongas los script al final del body después de poner toda tu estructura html.

Comment: Hola Jose, a que te refieres con funcionalidades agregadas?  
La llamada de los scripts estan al final del archivo, como lo indicas.
Cuando yo he trabajado con Ajax no he tenido problemas de este tipo, pero en este caso si y se me hace complicado jugar todas las partes del codigo donde se activan las funcionalidades para cargarlas con cada archivo que llamo mediante Ajax, ya que estoy usando una plantilla que encontre en internet y tiene muchisimas cosas. Espero encontrar otra soluciona

Comment: Por casualidad usas semantic?

Comment: Esta es la plantilla que uso: 
https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html
y aqui sus fuentes: 
https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella

Al final de importar todos los scripts, esta uno de nombre custom.min.js, aqui es donde estan todas las funcionalidades para los formularios

Comment: Revisa que el jQuery no se este sobre escribiendo (que tengas mas de una version de jQuery en la pagina)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio esta faltando información para saber cuál es el problema, de todos modos asumo que el problema es que las funciones js son ejecutadas antes de que estén listos los elementos que las ejecutan, esto se debe a que obviamente como cargas el contenido por Ajax los mismos no existen en ese momento.

Si usas Ajax para cargar contenido puedes usar ".done" para imprimir el js que quieres que se ejecute una vez terminada la carga del Ajax.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'archivo.php',
 method: 'post', //o get
 data: {xxx}, //en caso de que tengas datos para enviarle al php
 success: function(result){
  //en result tendrás la página cargada para imprimirla en el html.
 }
}).done(function(){
 //aquí insertas todos los scripts que quieres que sean llamados post carga de ajax.
});
```

Cualquier duda que tengas puedes consultar, en caso de que no lo entiendas te agradezco crear un codepen o jsfiddle con una situación similar para poder resolverlo.

Un saludo y suerte!